# Req.body equal undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to implement a contact form with node js, but on receiving the data in the backend, when I print it the req.body always shows "undefined". I am trying to send json data by javascript.
I already looked for information on the internet but nothing has solved my problem.

Frontend code that sends the JSON:

```
 const sendData = dataJSON => {
    let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = '/send-email';
    btnSend.addEventListener('click', async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        http.open('POST', url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/json');

        http.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) alert(http.responseText);
        };

        http.send(await dataJSON);
        console.log(dataJSON);
    });
};
```

En el backend:

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/send-email', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
res.send('Received');
});
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what `dataJSON` is please.

Comment: Can you try putting 'application/json' in the request header instead of 'text/json'

Comment: the `datJSON` equals to: {"fullName":"David Figueroa Lopez","userPhone":"98413210110","userEmail":"davesmarth@outlook.com","userPreferences":{"userPreferPhone":false,"userPreferEmail":true},"userMessage":"Hello"}

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code passing dataJSON as an object and it gave the same problem, but I managed to solve it as follows

```
let url = '/send-email'; // complete URL
...
http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
...
http.send(await JSON.stringify(dataJSON));
```

Comment: I already tried but it keeps printing 'undefined'. I don't know what to do anymore, but anyway, thanks.